# Could lacio and ἕλκω be related?

Tags: greek, etymology

Would it be at all possible for Latin *lacio* "pull, lure" (cf. *illicio, laqueus, lacesso, lacto*) to be related with Greek ἕλκω "draw, pull"? Wiktionary suggests no cognates of *lacio* are known, so there probably is no  established relation, but I am curious whether this would be at al possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ἕλκω is thought to be from a root *selk-, which actually has a Latin derivative in *sulcus* "furrow" (Gk. ὅλκος). As far as I can see there's no regular way to derive *laciō* from *selk-. (BTW de Vaan argues that *laqueus* is unrelated to the family of *laciō* because of the *qu*.)